# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

Доброго времени суток! встала задача перенести небольшой проект с php+mysql на iis 8+mssql,уткнулся в стену со следующей строчкой :

```
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {           
            if ($myrow['mesto'] != $ip_user)
                {
                $mesto = $myrow['mesto'];
                echo '<option value="'.$mesto.'">'.$mesto.'</option>';
                };
            };
```

Переделал в

```
while($myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {           
            if ($myrow['mesto'] != $ip_user)
                {
                $mesto = $myrow['mesto'];
                echo '<option value="'.$mesto.'">'.$mesto.'</option>';
                };
            };
```

Но получаю в логе вот такую ошибку :

sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

в строчке

```
while($myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: У вас запрос не выполнился и `$result` не является ресурсом, а равен  false

Comment: Перед fetch проверьте количество полученных записей. А лучше переделать на PDO и больше никогда этим не заниматься.

Comment: Да,ошибка в синтаксисе запроса. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете в функцию **sqlsrv_fetch_array** $result -> значение true/false.
А должны передавать объект выполненного запроса.